Upgrade from v13.2 to v13.13 breaks PostgreSQL triggers
We noticed that our table record geometry was not updating for spatial records with our defined special trigger. The trigger was not modified at any time after the PostgreSQL upgraded from 13.2 to 13.13, nor prior. Upon discovering this issue, it seemed like it was specific record. when we run the following update command, we receive the parse error noted below.

ERROR: parse error geometry   HINT: "polygon(102.793, 3" <-- Parse
error at position 13 withing geometry  SQL State: XX000

However, to debug the trigger issue I ran the following from an SQL Query panel:
UPDATE <table> SET geom = public.st_geomfromtext(format('polygon(%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s)', swlon,nelat, nelon,nelat, nelon,swlat, swlon,swlat, swlon,nelat), 4326)

Where  is the specific table name.
and, geom is our spatial column defined as geom geometry(POLYGON, 4326)
I received the same error as the trigger.
In the error cited above, I queried the "table" for 102.793 and found one unique record. There is nothing incorrect with the swlat/swlon and nelat/nelon values for this specific record. The four lat/lon values were correct. The trigger and the command above used the four spatial columns to great the geometry.
For the first coordinate pair - (swlon,nelat) is used for the first coordinate. I can query for 102.793 and get a unique hit but the nelon does not start with "3".
The first thing I attempted was to reset search_path for the primary db user.
alter role <user> set search_path to production, public;

This did not resolve the issue.
What is worrying me is that we recently upgraded from Postgre 13.2 to 13.13 and I'm wondering if something got reinitialized or clobbered in the upgrade. I did not perform the upgrade. I know they took a snapshot and restored from that.
Has anyone encountered such behavior following an upgrade?

The error tries to tell you that the WKT string literal is missing a (, as a valid WKT string for Polygons must have at least one ring (the shell/outer ring) defined in a pair of parenthesis nested one level deep. Looks to me like a simple typo - but it is not totally unheard of that a version migration routine sanitizes away perfectly valid string formatting.

Apologies on the typo in my original post. I'm not connected to the system which executes the SQL update command. Still get the parse error with the removal of the rogue ")". My observation is that it would not matter if the geom WKT value is corrupted (or not) since rerunning the SQL UPDATE command I cite should just replace all the WKT values -- regardless corrupt or not.  Maybe I need to reinstall the PostGIS libraries in Public.

It has to be POLYGON(( ... ))! I.e. public.st_geomfromtext(format('polygon((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s))', swlon,nelat, nelon,nelat, nelon,swlat, swlon,swlat, swlon,nelat), 4326)

You are so right geozelot! what's a missing parenthesis between firiend -- a big headache. Much thanks.

the error also show long, lat, using a comma instead of a space between the coordinates of the 1st point, which doesn't correspond to the update statement
